# I can't get pythons output viewer to run

Tags: python-3.x

I just downloaded python on a new pc and now whenever I try to create a script the output viewer just closes down immediately when I launch it as a python file.
My original script was

```
import secrets
secrets.token_hex(32)
```

but it just closes down immediately. I thought that it was something with my code so I tried to just make the simple "hello world" script.

```
(print) "I hope this work"
```

and I had the same result as the first script, the output window opened up then immediately closed down.
I can get it to work using the python shell but I prefer doing all my coding using notepad++ and it would a real pain in the behind if I can't get that to work.

Comment: How are you creating a script, and how are you running it? Btw print in Python 3 must be called as a function print(“Chease”)

Comment: I'm creating the scripts in notepad++ then I save them as Filename.py then I run them by clicking opening them from my file explorer. And yes I'm calling the print as a function just didn't copy paste the last script and must have missed that on the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior if you run your scripts as you described, by opening them in Explorer. Your script completes execution in a terminal window, then closes immediately.

If you absolutely insist on running them on double click and still want to see your console, I suggest you create a .bat file at your python path with contents like this:

```
python -i %1
```

and them bind your double-click handler to use that file on .py extension. That way, Python will execute your file and go into CLI mode, preserving your terminal window and allowing you to type further commands.

My other guess would be that you want a console plugin to work right within Notepad++, in that case use nppexec: https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/